# Get state of the ear after the Promotion is completed from weblogic maven plugin in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Deployed to weblogic by using the weblogic maven plugin through jenkins.

Is there any option where we can get the status of the ear file so i can redeploy the old ear if the ear status is not active.

How can we do this in Jenkins is there any plugin available?.
Trying to implement rollback process if the deployment failed.

```
<plugin> 
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId> 
        <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
        <version>10.3.6.0</version> 
        <configuration> 
          <adminurl>${ADMIN_URL}</adminurl>
          <user>${USER_NAME}</user> 
          <password>${PASSWORD}</password> 
          <upload>true</upload> 
          <action>deploy</action> 
          <remote>false</remote>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <targets>${TARGETS}</targets>
          <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
          <name>${project.build.finalName}</name> 
        </configuration> 
      </plugin>
```